# How to change IME mode (ON & OFF)?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

VBA for Microsoft Access.

Before showing a inputbox, how can I turn IME on or off in vba for microsoft access?

Comment: IMEMode is a property of a separate control, not of an access.application. Inputbox have no any parameter related to IME mode - and it is a function, not control.

Comment: You can do it in excel with API. I'm looking for a way to do it in Access.

Comment: This is for excel. I'm looking for a way for Access [link]https://pastebin.com/Hbc7qH6J

Comment: I do not know how to obtain InputBox.hWnd directly. Try to find its window - by a caption, for example...